# Perl/tk sans-serif font missing in Linux

Tags: perl, fonts, tk-toolkit

I have a perl/tk script that uses a canvas with text.
A while back the font of the text changed alone: no more sans-serif!
Probably some update/upgrade messed up my fonts, but they should be there somewhere. I only found this problem in perl/tk scripts.

I downloaded a small perl script that shows the installed fonts, and indeed no sans-serif appears. In fact, only 30 or so fonts appear. The command `xlsfonts` gives me more than 1600 fonts, yet `xfontsel` only shows these 30 font families.

How did the sans font disappear, and how do I restore/install back missing fonts?

This is the script I used to see the fonts:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Tk;
use Tk::BrowseEntry;
use strict;

my $mw = MainWindow->new(-title => 'Font Viewer');
my $f = $mw->Frame->pack(-side => 'top');

my $family = 'Courier';
my $be = $f->BrowseEntry(-label => 'Family:', -variable => \$family,
  -browsecmd => \&apply_font)->pack(-fill => 'x', -side => 'left');
$be->insert('end', sort $mw->fontFamilies);

my $size = 24;
my $bentry = $f->BrowseEntry(-label => 'Size:', -variable => \$size,
  -browsecmd => \&apply_font)->pack(-side => 'left');
$bentry->insert('end', (3 .. 32));

my $weight = 'normal';
$f->Checkbutton(-onvalue => 'bold', -offvalue => 'normal',
  -text => 'Weight', -variable => \$weight,
  -command => \&apply_font)->pack(-side => 'left');

my $slant = 'roman';
$f->Checkbutton(-onvalue => 'italic', -offvalue => 'roman',
  -text => 'Slant', -variable => \$slant,
  -command => \&apply_font)->pack(-side => 'left');

my $underline = 0;
$f->Checkbutton(-text => 'Underline', -variable => \$underline,
  -command => \&apply_font)->pack(-side => 'left');

my $overstrike = 0;
$f->Checkbutton(-text => 'Overstrike', -variable => \$overstrike,
  -command => \&apply_font)->pack(-side => 'left');

my $stext = 'Sample Text';
my $sample = $mw->Entry(-textvariable => \$stext)->pack(-fill => 'x');

&apply_font;

MainLoop;

sub apply_font {
  # Specify all options for font in an anonymous array
  $sample->configure(-font =>
    [-family => $family,
     -size => $size,
     -weight => $weight,
     -slant => $slant,
     -underline => $underline,
     -overstrike => $overstrike]);
}
```

Comment: The syntax you use doesn't work for me. I need to write `$sample->configure(-font => [$family, $size, $weight, $slant]);`. I wasn't able to make underline and overstrike work.

Comment: Both syntax work for me, but underline and overstrike only work with my syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In some of the last updates this has been fixed. Sans fonts are back.